# Writing to a File, Separating Values when Reading

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to teach myself to program, and one early subject I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is file IO.

So far I know I can save data separated by commas, in order to successfully read that data later. Doing something like the following:

```
int x[] = {1,22,333,4444,55555};
std::ofstream FileWriter;
std::string dataName = "One through Five";
for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    FileWriter << x[i] << ',';
}
FileWriter << dataName << std::endl;
FileWriter.close();
```

That is certainly easy enough, but that seems tacky and actually kind of inefficient. I wonder if there is a better way to save data and still have it separable when I go to read it later.

Unfortunately the searching I have done has only yielded the following:

```
std::getline( FileReader, myStringBuffer, ',');
```

So is it possible that I can store separate data points, such that they are distinguishable as separate at read time, **without the use** of a delimiting character at save time? That is to say, without separating data with some character or white-space.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to the question... but... as long as you can write the logic for parsing the data out after reading it, you can write it to file however you want.  In programming classes I've been in, we always learned reading from file before writing to file.  So, I'd suggest... before venturing to far down the path toward writing data to file that you intend to read back in later, I'd practice on just reading files.

Comment: iostream's [also have read and write functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/iostream/) which let you read and write binary data to which you know the underlying structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic binary file io practices will do what you want. When reading binary data, you need to know the size of each piece of data you are reading; knowing this will drive a lot of your design decisions. If you want to read in an int followed by a string, you need to know the size of an int (easily found by calling sizeof(int)) so that you can 'nibble off' an int's worth of data from the binary blob you are trying to load data from, then after you read the int's worth of data you need to know how big your string is. Since strings are variable in length, you either need to assume a standard length (yuck!), or read the length first FROM A KNOWN SIZE OF DATA, then read that many bytes into a string. So, your data writer needs to write out the length of strings (or any other variable-sized data type) before it writes out a string, as a known data size (like say write the size information as an unsigned int).

For clever ways to organize binary data for reading/writing, check out the Interchange File Format (IFF). It is what TIFF, RIFF etc are all based on, and is a great way to design a binary file blob. It basically stores data as "chunks", where the data first has a chunk ID written out, then the size of the chunk in bytes, then the data for that chunk. This way, a reader program can check chunk ID's, and if it doesn't want to/know how to handle a certain or even unknown type of data, it can skip ahead the chunk size in bytes and read the next chunk.

Comment: Just adding that for cross-platform programs, you will need to avoid dynamically using sizeof(int) etc to determine the number of bytes to read, as the platform that wrote out the int might have a different size defined for ints. Same goes for byte order issues; this is all stuff that you only worry about when writing more advanced, cross-platform code, though, so we'll skip it for this answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

Separating values by specific characters can work, depending you values: if you strings don't use the separating character, e.g., a comma, you can save the values using a comma a separator. Things become interesting when there is no character which is known to be a useful separate. The typical approach in that case is to use quoting together with suitable escape character, e.g., what C and C++ use to specific string literals:

- Normally strings start and with a single quote `"`.
- To embed a quote into a string it is escaped with by a backslash, e.g., `"\""`.
- To embed the escape character backslash, it uses two backslashes, e.g., `"\\"`.

Another approach which is sometimes used is to combine the values with a size prefix. What is used depends on the exact needs, though.

When you use comma as a separator, you probably need something to skip commas when reading formatted values, e.g., integers: they won't easily read over a comma and just ignoring it is probably not appropriate. If it is missing it is clearly a format error. You might want to use a manipulator to extra a comma when present:

```
std::istream& comma(std::istream& in) {
    std::istream::sentry cerberos(in);
    if (in && in.peek() == ',') {
        in.ignore();
    }
    else {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
// ...
int i, j;
if (in >> i >> comma >> j) { ... }
```

The input expression should read two comma separated integers and fail if either value isn't an `int` or they are not separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, **you wish to know how to store data in a format that you can read again (presumably in another C++ program).**

If so, then there are a number of ways in which you can do this:

The most common (and simplest) way of doing so is via:

1. Whitespace separated (e.g.):
   `value1 value2 value3`
2. Commas (this will generate a comma-separated file, more commonly known as a CSV file)
   `1,2,3`.
3. Or, any character at all:
   `1#2#3`

That way you can use `std::getline` like you did (e.g. for CSV):

```
char delim = ',';

while(std::getline(input_stream, temporary_string, delim) {
    //data handling goes here...
}
```

Of course, as this is a naive example (i.e. your data is structured as a table), you'll have to adapt your code to address more multifaceted data that spans more than one line often by reading in the data in chunks and parsing those chunks based on your format.

Complex Example (Satellite Coordinates):

```
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5
1.6   1.7 1.8 1.9
2.0        
2.0
2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
2.1     2.4
```

Which is whitespace delimited and has the following format:

1. Every data point is stored in the following pattern: data, space.
2. If a data point doesn't exist, it is represented by a space, unless it
   is the last non-existent data point where all other output is
   truncated to a newline.